# Closed form analytical expression for $\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda a} J_0(\lambda r) \sin(\lambda t) \, \mathrm{d}\lambda$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, bessel-functions

Consider the following function that is defined by an infinite integral
$$
I(r,t,a) = \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda a} J_0(\lambda r) \sin(\lambda t) \, \mathrm{d}\lambda \, ,  
$$
where $r, t,$ and $a$ are positive real numbers.
Here, $J_0$ denotes the zeroth order Bessel function of the first kind.

Clearly, the integral above in convergent.
i was wondering whether an explicit analytical expression for $I$ can be obtained analytically.

Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Please review the integral parameters (it should be $d\lambda$ I guess). Also what is the definition of $J_0$ ?

Comment: @LeBlanc It's a Bessel function

Comment: @LeBlanc Thanks for the comment. Yes, $J_0$ is the 0th order Bessel function

Comment: I'm aware that it's Bessel function. What i mean iss what definition are you using, or anything can be used?

Comment: @LeBlanc Bessel functions are uniquely defined. Here, i mean Bessel functions of the first kind, commonly denoted by $J$

Comment: I should have asked directly if one can use any integral representation, such as $J_0(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \cos(x\cos z) dz=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(x\cosh z)dz$.

Comment: For $I_0$ write $\sin (\lambda t)=\Im e^{i\lambda t}$, $\Im$ denoting the imaginary part, then using the laplace transform of the Bessel function: $\int_0^\infty e^{-ax} J_0 (bx)dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ we obtain $I_0=\Im \frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2+(a-it)^2}}$. For $I_{-1}$ integrate once the above with respect to a.

Comment: @LeBlanc Yes the identity should be applicable. If you could please post a clear answer illustrating the math steps that help solving the problem, that would be great.

Comment: I'm not sure how to integrate that imaginary part, so maybe someone else can show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to start with [Bessel's Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel's_integrals) and apply residue theorem. For simplicity make a change of variable to ensure $r = 1$. Then, we have

\begin{align*}I = \int_0^\infty e^{-(a-it)x} J_0(x)\,dx &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{\infty} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{-(a-it)x} e^{ix\sin \tau}\,d\tau\,dx \\&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-(a-i(t+\sin \tau))x} \,dx \,d\tau \\&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{1}{a-i(t+\sin \tau)} \,d\tau \\&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{|z| = 1} \frac{1}{a-i\left(t+\frac{1}{2i}\left(z - \frac{1}{z}\right)\right)} \,\frac{dz}{iz}\tag{$\ast$}\\&= \frac{i}{\pi} \int_{|z| = 1} \frac{1}{z^2 - 2(a-it)z - 1} \,dz\end{align*}

where, in step $(\ast)$ we made the change of variable $z = e^{i\tau}$.

The function has two simple poles at $\alpha^{\pm} = a-it \pm \sqrt{(a-it)^2 + 1}$ (where we are using the principle branch of square root since $a > 0$) and only $\alpha^{-}$ is inside the unit disk. Therefore, the integral is $$I = \frac{i}{\pi}\frac{2\pi i}{\alpha^- - \alpha^+} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(a-it)^2 + 1}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2 - t^2 + 1 - 2iat}}.$$

Now, comparing imaginary parts on both sides should give the result.

Comment: $-1/\pi$ in front of the last integral should be $i/\pi$.

Comment: Thanks .. You are right! Will fix it soon as I get near a pc.